# Efetuar função ao clicar exceto em item específico com jQuery

Tags: jquery, return

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
$(".teste").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Dentro dessa div `.teste` tenho links com a classe `.link` e quero que, ao clicar na div, ocorra o `return false`, mas que não ocorra o `return false` se eu clicar nos links (`.link`) que estão dentro da div. Já tentei:

```
$(".teste").not("a.link").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

tentei também:

```
$(".teste:not(a)").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Porém ambos não funcionaram.

HTML (exemplo):

```
<div class="teste">
    <div class="outradiv"></div>

    <div class="maisumadiv">
        <a href="/teste" class="link">Link...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar seu código HTML também para entendermos melhor a situação?

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo

Comment: Além do HTML coloque também o CSS, ou então um fiddle com o seu código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode capturar o target do evento, se for um link vc retorna `true`;

```js
$('.teste').on('click', function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is('a')) return true;
  alert('Click');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.teste {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='teste'>
  <div><a href='http://www.google.com.br'>Link 1</a></div>
  <div><a href='http://pt.stackoverflow.com/'>Link 2</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Bom, você já tem várias respostas, mas vou propor um outro método:

```js
$('.teste').click(function(e) {
   return !(e.target == this);
});
```

```css
.teste {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="teste">
    <a href="http://jsfiddle.net">teste</a>
</div>
```

Isso funciona porque o tratamento do clique nos links está delegado para um nível superior na hierarquia, o div. O `target` do evento é o elemento clicado, mas o `this` é sempre o elemento onde você "amarrou" o evento (no caso, o div). Portanto, se clicar em algo que não seja o próprio div, ou seja, qualquer coisa dentro do div, o evento não é cancelado (`return true`), senão ele é cancelado (`return false`).

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja isso que você quer:

```
$(".teste, .link").on('click', function() {
     if ($(this).attr('class')=='link') {
        return true;
     } 
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".teste").find(".link").click(function() {
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Adicione algum conteúdo explicativo na sua resposta para que possa ser útil para membros com menos conhecimento no futuro.